# How to post on friend's timeline in Android Facebook SDKs 4.1+

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here, I just want to post something on a friend's wall or send him text using Facebook SDK 4.1 but I'm not getting any successful result.

[Here, I found that we cannot send any chat messages to anyone.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat)

So I integrated Messenger app in my application. Without having native app of Messenger, I'm not able to send anything here.
I have added some permissions which are `read_custom_friendlists,public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends,publish_actions`

I can update on my Timeline using this code

```
  private void postStatus() {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Hello UTU")
            .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11114/111141352/3551664-iron-man-6800-hd-wallpapers.jpg"))
            .build();

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
    //    ShareApi.share(content, null);

}
```

I tried to get friend's list by using Graph API

```
AccessToken accesstoken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/{friendlist-id}",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

When I debug my code it says, Access Token Permission is removed. And it just come out of the method, it never goes to the next line. I have searched alot.

But I didn't get anything to post on my friend's wall.

Does anyone know anything ? Please share your ideas or codes.

Comment: Do you have `publish_actions` permission from facebook for this app ?

Comment: I have "public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends,publish_actions".

Comment: @  Anshul Tyagi : Did facebook approved your permission request and yes  are you using same account as you used for facebook developer ?

Comment: Nope it still shows an image infront of Status & review and App details.

Comment: @AndiGeeky actually I need code also for doing it with new versions of SDK.

Comment: @  Anshul Tyagi : Then edit your question and ask for code also..!!

Comment: Edited. Have you ever done this?

Comment: @ Anshul Tyagi :Nope ..All i have done with Facebook is posting status and image on own timeline..!!

Comment: Alright. I think this function is deprecated in android now. But it's not officially mentioned.

Comment: @ Anshul Tyagi : I think you shold try `GraphApis`..!!

Comment: I have no idea of them. And I'm not getting any code of them also.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t post on the wall of a friend, for obvious reasons. It would always be spam. Also, you only get a list of friends who authorized your App too, and the API call is `/me/friends`.

The Chat API is gone, so you can´t send messages to friends either.

Just use the Social Plugins (Share Dialog, Send Dialog, ...) to do all that stuff, no authorization needed for those.

Comment: I tried MessageDialog but it never works if you don't have native app of Messenger.

Comment: yes, that is correct. there is no workaround for this afaik.

Comment: Do you have any official doc which says that "you can't post on the wall of a friend." ? I have about chat only https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

Comment: this has been discussed in countless threads in the facebook developers group, it´s what facebook employees say. and friend permission have been removed, just look at the changelog.

Comment: as you can read in my answer, the chat api is gone and there is no replacement

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation

Comment: you can also look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog